# RGB to HEX not converting correctly

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to convert RGB to HEX but my EditText which holds the Hex value does not show `0`

This is my code:

```
     etHexVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHex);
     if (etHexVal.length() == 6) { //has 000000

     }
     if (etHexVal.length() < 6) { //anything else
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter SIX characters/numbers combination", 2000).show();
     }
     etHexVal.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             String filtered_str = s.toString();
             if (filtered_str.matches(".*[^A-F^0-9].*")) {
                 filtered_str = filtered_str.replaceAll("[^A-F^0-9]", "");
                 s.clear();
                 s.append(filtered_str);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only A-F and 0-9 is allowed", 2000).show();
             }
         }
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

         }
     });
private int getColorFromSeekbars()
{
    return Color.argb(255, redSeek.getProgress(), greenSeek.getProgress(), blueSeek.getProgress());
}
private String displayHexVal() {
    String k = "" + redSeek.getProgress() + greenSeek.getProgress() + blueSeek.getProgress() + "";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), k, 2000).show();
    String strColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & Integer.valueOf(k));
    return strColor;
}
```

I have three Seekbars and if RED seekbar is 0 and GREEN seekbar is 0 and BLUE seekbar is 146, I want to display `000092` in the `etHexVal` edittext but it only shows `00009`. If RED is 0 GREEN is 85 and BLUE is 146 the `etHexVal` displays 014C9 instead of #005592. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're not getting the correct values in your String. Try doing the following:

In your displayHexVal() replace `String k ...` with:

```
public String k = getHexFromInt(redSeek.getProgress()) + getHexFromInt(greenSeek.getProgress()) + getHexFromInt(blueSeek.getProgress());
```

and add the method below:

```
public String getHexFromInt(int val){
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append(Integer.toHexString(val));
     if (sb.length() < 2) {
         sb.insert(0, '0'); // add leading zero if necessary
     }
     String hex = sb.toString();

     return hex;
}
```

To revert the String back to ints, do the following (Note: you may want to add error-handling here):

```
public int[] getIntsFromHex(String hex){
    int[] results = new int[3];

    results[0] = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(0,2),16);
    results[1] = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2,4),16);
    results[2] = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(4,6),16);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Haha, yes. I forgot to rename it.

Comment: When I changed the value for GREEN my app just crashed.

Comment: Nevermind I had to modify part of my code as well to match yours... and it's working!!! Thanks

Comment: Your String `strColor` should no longer be needed. `k` should give you your 005592. If you want the # prepended, add it to the beginning of `k`.

Comment: One issue If I choose 93,116,114 the hex value is displaying 57472 but not 5D7472. I have to convert to UPPERCASE :)

Comment: How would I do the opposite? Convert HEX to RGB? BTW Upvoted and Accepted your answer :) Should I open a new question?

Comment: I got the function... it's ok Thank you for the assistance :) Plus let me ask a new question so you get credit twice.

Comment: No need for that. I added it to this answer.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks! I am already doing the error check while user is entering the value :)